# Make TimeWithZone objects lazy in Rails

Tags: ruby, performance, profiling

How do I make `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` faster to construct or lazy?

I've been profiling my Rails app and I've found that a third of the cpu time is spent constructing these `TimeWithZone` objects. I'm at my wits end with this. How is it possible that seemingly simple time objects can be so expensive to construct?

Here is the code that is run a bazillion times per request:

```
def deserialize_from_cache(json)
  attributes = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)
  attributes.keys.to_a.each do |k|
    v = attributes[k]
    if v.is_a? Array and v.length == 2 and v[0] == 'Time'
      attributes[k] = Time.at(v[1]).in_time_zone # This is the expensive code
    end
  end
  self.allocate.init_with('attributes' => attributes)
end
```

I benchmarked plain old `Time` object construction and found it to be an order of magnitude faster than the `TimeWithZone` construction:

```
puts Benchmark.measure { 200000.times { Time.at(1330367843) } }
  0.070000   0.000000   0.070000 (  0.068956)

puts Benchmark.measure { 200000.times { Time.at(1330367843).in_time_zone } }
  0.720000   0.000000   0.720000 (  0.715802)
```

Is there something that I can do to programmatically replace all of the models' datetime attributes with lazy `TimeWithZone` objects that are plain old (and cheap) `Time` objects until they are used at which time they are turned into `TimeWithZone` objects? This is far beyond my Ruby abilities.

Comment: Your benchmarks give fairly different results on my laptop (Thinkpad Ubuntu 11.10 Ruby 1.9.3 p125, Rails 3.2.3).  I see the #at method and #in_time_zone taking almost exactly the same time. Results from your code:  Time.at:  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.054021); Time.at.in_time_zone:  0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.115737)

Answer (score 0):

The thing that strikes me about this question is that the code you are focusing on is being called from within `deserialize_from_cache(json)`.  Why is *that* being called so often?  Could you perhhaps look further up the call chain and see if you can reduce the amount of json-to-time parsing?